# Which way to cin n positive integers faster?

Tags: input

I wonder which way is the best to cin n positive integers (with unknown n)?

```
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int x;
    while (cin >> x){...}
```

```
    cin.tie(NULL);
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    for (char c : s){...}
```

or using get char (but I do not know how to use getchar)